# callback of Itemselected doesn't work in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uwp

I have a simple two pages.

One has a listview.

So when clicks an item of the listView, go to another page.

But I click default back button on my win phone then I click an item of one again, navigation page doesn't work completely.

Here is my code snippet.

```
in first page
listview.itemselected += listview_ItemSelected;
private void listview_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.SelectedItem = null){
  }
  else {
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => Navigation.PushAsync(new twopage()));
  }
}
```

Please be aware that I am testing on UWP Project based on Xamarin.Form.

Comment: the ListView probably thinks that the item is already selected, so it doesn't fire the event again.  Try setting ItemSelected = null before you navigate to the 2nd page

Comment: Still the same.

Answer (score 0):

[MainPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKDHR.png)

[Page1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUVtH.png)

this is my screen short

step 1

```
 public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var mainpage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        MainPage = mainpage;
    }
```

---

step2

```
 private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        var page = new Page1();
        Navigation.PushAsync(page);

    }
```